# A Daily Pet picture in 'The Litter Box' chat room

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, chat

The chat room for [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) - [The Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) has a *Daily floof* pinned to the side of the chat. Which is a link with the current date to an image of a cute animal.

Why don't we do the same, but call it the *Daily Pet*?

Any room owner or mod from any site can pin the message. One can be inserted each day and the old one unpinned.

Comment: I like :) Where would the pics come from?

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver our own pics of our pets and other people's pets, family, friends.

Comment: With 13 - 17 cats, and no end of antics, I could probably run my own *cute pet* feed. Not that I'd want to, but with the suspected number of active chat users a new pic every day should be easy to maintain.

Comment: We need to formulate a system- so one person isn't taking over i.e. me - I'm happy for people to ping me to pin stuff, maybe people should just post there pics and ping a mod

Comment: If the idea is accepted, then set a window of time (UTC) when users can post their "pic of the day". Everyone can star any pics they like. Set a different time, an hour or two after the window closes, for end of voting. Then pin the one with the most stars. Helps users get the "talkative" and "outspoken" badges at the same time. =D

Comment: Of course, a score of 2 isn't decisive yet either.

Answer (score 3):

This is less an answer of Do we want a Daily Pet, as the chat users are creating one anyway.

This shows how to link and pin the Daily Pet.

**Copy Link**

Hover the mouse over the drop down arrow at the top left of the image.

[image]

Right click the mouse over the drop down arrow.

Select *Copy Link Address*

[image]

**Add link as comment**

Then add the link to the chat room via a message. Using the format `[Daily Pet yyyy-mm-dd](the copied link address)`. Leave no spaces between the [] and (). The chat has bumped the link onto the next line.

[image]

**Pin Message**

Only Room owners or moderators can pin the messages.

If you are not a room owner or moderator, @ping someone who is, to pin the Daily Pet message. Try and find someone who has been recently active.

Click on the drop down arrow for the message and select *pin this message*.

[image]

**Unpin the previous Daily Pet**

Go to the drop down arrow to the right of the pinned message. Select *unpin this item*.

[image]

Comment: Would this still be an option for the mobile version? I've had some issues using the mobile stack, specifically with click and drop options and formatting working correctly - example- for nominating mod- my mobile version wouldn't auto format for me to fill in :(

Comment: I don't use the mobile version @ChristyB. I've heard a lot of people complain of difficulties with it